# What is the mistake with my Android animation of my ImageView?

Tags: java, android, animation, imageview

This code works only for the first animation. Though the final position of the ImageView is not exactly the point of the MotionEvent and the animation looks not smooth. The result of all other MotionEvents is actually no animation. The ImageView just appears at the point i touch the screen.

Here is the code.

```
ImageView image;
MyAnimationListener am;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    am = new MyAnimationListener(image);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent mEvent){

    if(mEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        TranslateAnimation tAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(image.getX(),mEvent.getX(),image.getY(),mEvent.getY());
        tAnimation.setDuration(500);
        am.setCoordinates(mEvent.getX(), mEvent.getY());
        tAnimation.setAnimationListener(am);

        AnimationSet aSet = new AnimationSet(true);
        aSet.addAnimation(tAnimation);
        image.startAnimation(aSet);
    }

    return true;
}
```

And the interesting methods of MyAnimationListener.

```
ImageView i;
float x,y;

public MyAnimationListener(ImageView i){
    this.i = i;
}

public void setCoordinates(float x, float y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    i.setX(x);
    i.setY(y);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use mEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE case also.. as it continuosly track as we move finger...while action down traces the point where we tap on first cordiante before move

Comment: Okay. But that does not solve the proble. The code works for the first tap. All following taps produce no animation. And i cant figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to do call a fillAfter so that the postion is not reset at the end of the animation. see [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html#setFillAfter%28boolean%29)